# Shell script question

Tags: shell, scripting

just curious if this will actually run, I modelled it after an example from someone elses script. My big worries are

- Is the variable included when the script is run?
- In the case statements, will the echo / mv / & close work correctly?

**Code Updated**

```
#! /bin/sh

    #save as ads.sh
    #run command: chmod +x ads.sh
    #usage ./ads.sh {on|off}

#stop framework
#/etc/init.d/framework stop

#create backup dir if needed
mkdir -p /var/local/adunits.bkp

    #if ads.sh on
    case "$1" in
    on)

      #move, touch, exit
      echo "Turning Ad support on..."
      mv /var/local/adunits/* /var/local/adunits.bkp
      ;;

    #if ads.sh off
    off)

      #remove tmp
      echo "Ads turned off..."
      mv /var/local/adunits.bkp/* /var/local/adunits
      ;;

    #else
    *)

      echo "Usage: ./ads.sh {on|off}"
      exit 1
      ;;

    esac

#restart framwork
#/etc/init.d/framework start

#bye
exit 0
```

Thanks ahead!

Comment: The best way to find out if it will run is to run it.

Comment: Unfortunetly I can't I don't have a device to run it from

Comment: Belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mv` commands look possibly dodgy.  From a mv man page:

```
mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

Note that the last argument should be a target file or directory.

So things like:

```
mv /src_dir/* /target_dir/*
```

Are likely to overwrite the 'last' file in `/target_dir` - which is probably not what you want.

```
mv /src_dir/* /target_dir
```

is probably what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the variable included when the script is run?

What variable are you referring to?

> In the case statements, will the echo / mv / & close work correctly?

The `mv` commands probably won't do what you want them to.  You can't generally have a wildcard (`*`) in both the source and target arguments of `mv`.  `man mv` for more information.  Remember that wildcards are expanded by the shell, not by `mv`; the `mv` command itself will only see a list of arguments, and has no way of knowing that there was a `*` in the second argument.

Comment: variable is included ala ./ads.sh on or ./ads.sh off, I didn't see my second wild card, oops!